# How can I use accented characters in the echo command in Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, special-characters

Hello people of Stack Overflow. Me and my friend are making a game in the Batch/.bat programming language. Up until this point, we have had no problems that we couldnt fix. When I started translating it into the Spanish version, however, we ran into problems. When I tried to have the program "echo" words in Spanish with accents (e.g. Á, É) it wouldnt work. I had set up a test page which had the program echo `"áéíóú"` but it came out with something else, I cannot copy and paste it right now. I ran into a similar problem when I tested the Russian/Cyrillic keyboard. I had set the character set to 437 when testing the accents and 1251 when testing the Russian. When I saved it, the special characters even changed in the Bat file code. Is there anything special I need to do to make the special characters appear? Again, I am only trying to use them on the echo command.

Answer (score 3):

- Save the batch file in UTF-8 *without BOM signature* and use UTF-8 codepage:

  ```
  chcp 65001 >nul
  echo Päivää Привет Hello
  ```
- Or make a file with messages for each language and *save it in unicode encoding (UTF-16LE)*:

  ```
  en.hello=Hello
  .......other messages
  fi.hello=Päivää
  .......other messages
  ```

  Then load the translations:

  ```dos
  set LANGUAGE=fi
  ...............
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in ('type "%~dp0messages.txt') do (
      if "%%a"=="%LANGUAGE%" set "msg.%%b"
  )
  ...............
  echo %msg.hello%
  ```

  Now the messages should be displayed correctly by default since the system console codepage usually corresponds to the language set in regional settings.

  > Päivää

  You can keep these messages in readable form inside the batch file saved as UTF-8 *without BOM signature* and use an embedded VBScript/powershell code to extract to `messages.txt` in UTF16-LE encoding:

  ```
  ::msg.en.hello=Hello
  ::msg.fi.hello=Päivää
  powershell -c "Get-Content '%~f0' -encoding UTF8 | Select-String -Pattern '^::msg\.' | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '::msg.',''} | Set-Content '%temp%\messages.txt' -encoding Unicode"
  ```

  And then load it as shown above.

Comment: When I did the `chcp 65001` thing it displayed the lines correctly. Thank you so much. This has been stumping me forever.

Answer (score -1):

Use in batch file

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

@CHCP 65001 >NUL

Comment: Is this relevantly different from the 2015s answer ?