# Dotted characters in cmd file output

Tags: cmd, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to write to file list of folders and subfolders from a given folder. I use this command:

```
dir /s /b /o:n /a:d > folderlist.txt
```

Dotted characters are not present in the output file. Output of command contains also dotted characters when I check it in `cmd`. I don't use PowerShell.

Comment: Please elaborate what is a dotted character. It would be nice to see an example of what you're expecting and what you get.

Comment: @montonero I'm assuming he means that `filename.txt` becomes `filename txt`. Since the `/A`-flag enables this, i 'm guessing that is what he's after.

Comment: @montonero : These characters are: áéőöüóúű.

Comment: @Joel : No, points are visible in output file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use accented characters in the echo command in Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723388/how-can-i-use-accented-characters-in-the-echo-command-in-batch)

Comment: @LotPings : I don't use PowerShell or echo command, just look for a simple solution.

Comment: @plaidshirt can you please run the command `chcp 65001` and then run your query again? Please re-read my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Joel : Alright, it is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the characters you need are not avaliable by default, please run: `chcp 65001` - this will change the encoding to UTF-8.

Then you can run your command: `dir /s /b /o:n /a:d > folderlist.txt`.

If you need to view the output in the cmd. Please change the default font to `Lucida Console`.

---

Before OP clarified what he was after, i managed to come up with this:

Assuming your filesystem is of reasonable size, you can use the `tree` command, which produces a indented tree-structure for you. You can tell it to use ASCII characters also with the `/A` flag. Try it out!

cmd: `tree /A ["directory path"] > "DRIVE_LETTER:\PATH_TO_EXPORT\tree.txt"`

`/A` - ASCII characters instead of extended characters.

`/F` - Display the names of the files in each folder.

Note that the `"directory path"` is optional, but it seems like you want to use it in this case (insert the path of your starting-folder).

If you cant use `tree` (for simple output reasons) - you can use:

`DIR YOUR_DRIVE_LETTER:\ /B /S > "DRIVE_LETTER:\PATH_TO_EXPORT\tree.txt"`

`/B`-flag = full path instead of relative path.

powershell: `Get-ChildItem | tree > "DRIVE_LETTER:\PATH_TO_EXPORT\tree.txt"`

Answer (score 0):

If `tree` solution is not suitable for you then you could run cmd with unicode support `cmd /u`. Or change codepage to UTF inside of batch file with `chcp 65001`.

Comment: Sure it's not, but whatever.