# German Umlauts in Powershell called by vbs

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, vbscript, character-encoding

i do have a ps1 file, which create a Link

**create-link.ps1**

```
$path = $env:HOMESHARE + "\My Projects\"
If(!(test-path $path))
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
}

$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($env:HOMESHARE + "\My Projects\" + "linkname.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "\\path\for\link"
$Shortcut.Description = "äöüß"
$Shortcut.IconLocation = $env:SYSTEMROOT + "\\system32\\shell32.dll,3"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

I also do have a vbs file which calls the ps1

**create-link.vbs**

```
command = "powershell.exe Get-Content ""C:\path\to\file\create-link.ps1"" | PowerShell.exe -noprofile"
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.Run command,0
```

Both files are saved with utf-8 encoding.

This construction was necessary, because the ps1 needed to run completly headless without any noticable things for the user. Calling a ps1 through a vbs solved this problem, if there is a better way i would be happy if you let me know.

If i am calling the powershell script directly or with "powershell.exe Get-Content ""C:\path\to\file\create-link.ps1"" | PowerShell.exe -noprofile" (by using cmd) everything works fine.
However, if i call the vbs to do the work it works in general, but the german umlauts from 'Description' are just questions marks, so somehow the encoding got scrambled. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) also has a `-Encoding` parameter.

Comment: Why do you call Powershell at all instead of creating the link from VBS?

Comment: @zett42 I assume that the only reason that VBS is in the picture at all is to compensate for PowerShell's inability to launch _itself_ hidden - see [GitHub issue #3028](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028).

Comment: i'm still working on it, but havn't beent successful yet..but thanks so far, i will accept it as soon as i can make it work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use accented characters in the echo command in Batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33723388/how-can-i-use-accented-characters-in-the-echo-command-in-batch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

- Save your `*.ps1` file as UTF-8 *with BOM*.
- Simplify your command by using the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PowerShell.exe)'s `-File` parameter:

```
command = "powershell.exe -NoProfile -File ""C:\path\to\file\create-link.ps1"""
```

See also:  [GitHub issue #3028](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028), which requests the ability to launch PowerShell *itself* completely hidden - obviating the need for an aux. VBScript script -  which [a future version may support](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3028#issuecomment-675714111) (but it won't be back-ported to Windows PowerShell).

---

**If you're using *Windows PowerShell* (versions up to v5.1), you must save your `*.ps1` files as UTF-8 *with a BOM*** in order for them to be interpreted correctly with respect to characters outside the ASCII (7-bit) range, such as `äöüß`.
This is no longer necessary in *PowerShell [Core] v6+*, which consistently defaults to UTF-8, but if your scripts need to run in *both* editions, you should always use UTF-8 *with BOM*.

If a given `*.ps1` doesn't have a BOM, Windows PowerShell interprets each byte that is part of an UTF-8 encoding *sequence* (all non-ASCII characters are encoded as 2-4 bytes) *individually* as a character, based on the system's active ANSI code page (a single-byte encoding such as Windows-1252).

On a US-English system, where the active ANSI code page is Windows-1252, the above sample string therefore surfaces as garbage string `Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃŸ`

Note that question marks, or, more accurately, instances of `�` (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, [`U+FFFD`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd)), would only surface in the *reverse* scenario: when ANSI-encoded text is misinterpreted as UTF-8.

---

As an aside, re your approach of providing the source code to the PowerShell CLI *via the pipeline (stdin)*:

Since your script apparently runs hidden, it won't make a difference in your case, but note that this technique exhibits pseudo-interactive mode and also doesn't support passing *arguments* to the script being provided via stdin - see [GitHub issue #3223](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3223)

Comment: alternativly, as a quick and dirty workaround, you could replace the umlaut with unicode, so ' "Brücke" ' becomes ' "Br" + " + [char]0x00FC + "cke" '

Comment: @bob Would never recommend that, even as a quick and dirty hack. Seen far too many people not treat encoding correctly and hacks like this are no better.

Comment: @Lankymark i completely agree, but i needed a very quick 'this must work NOW' solution, while working on a better one and switching them later